# Create a map from a 2 level nested list where key is part of the nested list's object?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a simple nested structure as such:

```
public static class A {
    private List<B> classBList;

    // constructor, getters, etc.
}

public static class B {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

I want to create a map of `<Integer,List<A>>` where the integer field in class `B` `id` will be the key, and the `A` objects in the input that contain the matching `id` will be rolled up into a list as the value. The input would be a list of class `A`.

So for example:

Input:

```
[classBList=[B{id:1, name:"Hello"}, B{id:2, name:"Hi"}],
classBList=[B{id:3, name:"No"}, B{id:3, name:"Go"}],
classBList=[B{id:1, name:"Yes"}]]
```

Output:

```
{Key=1, Value=[ A{classBList=[B{id:1, name:"Hello"}, B{id:1, name:"Yes"}]} ]

{Key=2, Value=[ A{classBList=[B{id:2, name:"Hi"}]} ]

{Key=3, Value=[ A{classBList=[B{id:3, name:"No"}, B{id:3, name:"Go"}]} ]
```

I'm having trouble, however, writing the lambdas that allow this to happen. What I tried:

```
Map<Integer, List<A>> heyThere = classAListInput.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        A::getClass,
        element -> element.getClassBList().stream()
            .map(B::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

But this doesn't compile, so really not sure of how the syntax should look.

If you're wondering why not just alter the map so it's <Integer, List< B >>, there are other fields in class A that I didn't note but would be needed in the output, so that's why a list of A objects would be the value in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to rebuild instances of `A` class with the new list of `B`.

However, expected output shows that there is only one `A` entry in the list, and all `B`'s are added to **the same `A` instance**:

```
{Key=2, Value=[ A{classBList=[B{id:2, name:"No"}, B{id:2, name: "Go"}, B{id:2, name:"Yellow"}, B{id:2, name:"Joe"}, B{id:2, name:"Blow"}]} ]
```

So, the following implementation may be offered assuming there's an all-args constructor in `A` class accepting `List<B>`:

```java
Map<Integer, List<A>> result = classAListInput
    .stream() // Stream<A>
    .flatMap(a -> a.getClassBList().stream()) // Stream<B>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        B::getId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(), // List<B> flattening all B instances by id
            lst -> List.of(new A(lst)) // or Arrays.asList or Collections.singletonList
        )
    ));
```

---

**Update**

As the copies of `A` class may need to be created with some additional fields in `A` class and the filtered list of `B` instances, the following change may be offered using `Map.entry` (available [since Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) which has been around for a while).

Also, to address an issue of duplicated entries for the same `bKey` inside the same `A` instance, `Stream::distinct` operation should be applied after mapping to the key field:

```java
Map<Integer, List<A>> aByBKey = classAListInput.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> a.getClassBList()
        .stream()
        .map(B::getBKey)
        .distinct()
        .map(bk -> Map.entry(bk, getCopy(a, bk)) )
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
    ));

aByBKey.forEach((bKey, a) -> System.out.println(bKey + " -> " + a));
```

where `getCopy` is a static method constructing a copy instance of `A` keeping the code of class `A` intact:

```java
public static A getCopy(A a, int bKey) {
    return new A(
        a.aKey, 
        a.classBList
            .stream()
            .filter(b -> b.getBKey() == bKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

[JDoodle example](https://jdoodle.com/ia/xRh)

Comment: This almost works perfectly, however the problem is I don't want to be creating new instances of A because there are other attributes in the A class besides classBList, so I would need access to the A element that's currently being evaluated. [See here](http://jdoodle.com/ia/xQI)

Comment: If there are _other_ fields in `A`, then there should be a mix of A fields with specific B instances, and you need to define how you map various A containers to their B items.  Generally, this is rather a drastic change to your initial requirement and it sounds like a new question.

Comment: Well there's no interest in changing the other A fields. So if the output map is bKey -> list of A's, I just want to remove the B elements from the classBList field within A that don't match the key of the map entry. Not sure if you still may consider a drastic change

Comment: This implies that if A contains several bKeys in general case. then additional A instances need to be created for each bKey-- say, there's A(111, [b = 1, b = 2]), A(222, [b=1, b = 3]) ==> 1 -> [A(111, [b = 1]), A(222, [b = 1])], 2 -> [A(111, [b = 2])], 3 -> [A(222, [b = 3]]

Comment: Hey check out what I wrote [here](http://https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xR0). This is close to exactly what I want, except there's repeating values in a map entry if a bKey appears twice in a classBList (see the output). So not sure what I may need to change in one of the intermediary lambdas

Comment: @pleasedontbemeantome you may check the update

Comment: So just to make sure I know what's actually going on here: Everything within .flatMap leads to a Stream of Map entries, where the keys are the bKeys we want (reduced to the distinct ones within every input list), and the values are the newly created A instances. So can you walk me through what's happening inside the .collect?

Comment: In `collect` the stream of the mentioned map entries is grouped by the keys=bKeys and the values are remapped to `A` copies  which are collected to list.

Comment: Would you maybe have a resource / advice for learning how to get better at chaining all these lambdas? It's definitely a blind spot for me and the only resources I've found really just cover basics

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to flat map to some sort of tuple class, like `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`, so you can stream `A` and `B` in parallel and then invert the grouping:

```
classAListInput.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getClassBList()
                .stream()
                .map(b -> new SimpleEntry<>(b.getId(), a)))
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())))
```

Comment: I get a can't reference a non-static method from a static context error on the Entry::getKey and Entry::getValue usages, which I think when working with lambdas means there's some kind of type mismatch.

Comment: Are you sure you imported `Map.Entry`?

Comment: Yes - from the Java Util class

Comment: Other than a missing parenthesis (corrected), [compiles fine for me](https://ideone.com/E0Bw23).

Comment: That parenthesis did the trick actually. So I think this is close, however what if the B ID's could be unique within A, and also if the B ID could appear in several different A objects? I updated the input in the OP to show what I mean by that. This solution would place values in the map where the B ID doesn't match the key

Comment: Then you'll want to flat map all the B's and construct new A's to encapsulate each group. If there are other variable fields on A you'll have to decide how to merge them.

Comment: "Decide how to merge them" So this is the big part I'm not sure about then - what would be an efficient way to merge the variables?

Comment: It's not a question of efficiency. It's a logical question only you can answer. If A0.name = "foo" and A1.name = "bar", but they share ids, which A one do you want to group them under?

Comment: The other A fields aren't really relevant - if the output map is bKey -> list of A's, then in that example you mentioned they would be separate A instances in the entry value. Take a look at this [demo](http://https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xQJ), it may better illustrate what I'm trying to get at

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, judging by the sample data, you have a `List<List<B>>` as an input.

And based on the sample output you've provided, you need to obtain a map of type `Map<Integer,A>` as a result (**not** a `Map<Integer,List<A>>`).

This can be done in the following steps:

- flatten the data using `flatMap()`, i.e. transform a `Stream<List<B>>` into a `Stream<B>`;
- group the elements by `id` by the means of collector [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function));
- collect the elements mapped to the same key into a list and transform them into an object `A`, which can be done by applying a combination of collectors [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) and `toList()` as the downstream of `groupingBy()`.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<B>> classAListInput = List.of(
        List.of(new B(1, "Hello"), new B(1, "Hi"), new B(1, "Bye"), new B(1, "Yes")),
        List.of(new B(2, "No"), new B(2, "Go"), new B(2, "Yellow")),
        List.of(new B(2, "Joe"), new B(2, "Blow"))
    );
    
    Map<Integer, A> aById = classAListInput.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)      // flattening the data
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            B::getId,                     // grouping by id
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),      // accumulating elements into a list
                A::new)                   // instantiating object A based on the List<B>
        ));
    
    aById.forEach((id, a) -> System.out.println(id + " -> " + a));
}
```

*Output:*

```
1 -> A{classBList=[B{id=1, name='Hello'}, B{id=1, name='Hi'}, B{id=1, name='Bye'}, B{id=1, name='Yes'}]}
2 -> A{classBList=[B{id=2, name='No'}, B{id=2, name='Go'}, B{id=2, name='Yellow'}, B{id=2, name='Joe'}, B{id=2, name='Blow'}]}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xhF)

Comment: Hey I updated your Online Demo to reflect how I think the input actually looks: [Updated Demo](http://jdoodle.com/ia/xQy). This doesn't compile though so I'm not quite sure where I went wrong. But basically the input wouldn't be a List of Lists, it would be a list of As with the B lists already embedded within them. So I wouldn't be creating new A objects necessarily

Comment: @pleasedontbemeantome *"input wouldn't be a List of Lists"* - Fine, it would be way **better** if input list from the demo would be added to the question.

Comment: @pleasedontbemeantome *"doesn't compile"* - sure, in your code expect the result to be of type `Map<Integer, A>`, meanwhile it's a `Map<Integer,List< A>>`.  Spicing of `Map.Entry`, firstly it's unjustifiable to use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` is with JDK 9+ (judging by the usage of `List.of()`). And even Java 9 `Map.entry()` isn't a very nice options because at the end of the day you end up faceless methods `getKey/getValue` and it requires more effort to read the code. Therefore, the approach of using a `record` is cleaner.

Comment: Well Record is only available in J16+ so I can't use that actually (my usage is on J8). As for the compile error, yeah sorry I didn't realize I forgot to fix up the Map types. Here is an [updated demo](http://jdoodle.com/ia/xQH), however this gives me empty outputs so still not quite sure which intermediate lamba went wrong here.

Comment: @pleasedontbemeantome With Java 8 you can use a plain class. And if you feel like writing getters and constrictors is a burden, add *Lombok* to your project to dialing with a boilerplate code, just declare field and place a couple of annotations.

Comment: So even if I [try a plain wrapper class](http://jdoodle.com/ia/xQJ), still not sure how to affect the A element that's being copied over, so that elements in the classBList are not present if they don't match the currently evaluating bKey?

Comment: @pleasedontbemeantome I've checked the code. That's the classic illustration of why pure functions are good and mutating arguments is evil. The answer would be - don't change existing `A` instances, create new instances instead.

Comment: Gotcha, so how would you then efficiently copy over the fields to a new instance? If say the A class has 20 different fields, and I just want to mutate the classBList to remove the elements you don't want. Also, not sure if mutating is even necessary here if there is a way to map the items correctly.

Comment: @pleasedontbemeantome 20 fields is smell, to begin with (don't get offended). Normally I would recommend introducing an instance method like `getCopy()` delegating to the constructor. But in your case, it might be tedious. There are some workarounds, maybe it's doable with MapStruct framework (I'm not using it, therefore can't tell for sure).

Comment: Well I say 20 fields but that's just an exaggeration for if the class were to grow to that size. But let's say the copying is trivial, if I'm able to just make some kind of deep copy trivially. How would that work then where I can merge the copied fields with the updated field?

Comment: Sorry so I'm a bit confused by that - so I have an instance method to copy unchanged A fields to a new A instance which makes sense, but what was your idea in terms of getting the changed ClassBList into the new A instance? Check out the commented area here, not sure if [this is what you meant](http://jdoodle.com/ia/xQR)

Comment: @pleasedontbemeantome Sorry, I was not attentive. No, the method don't need `A` as an argument, since `getCopy()` creates a copy of `this`, and it should reside inside `A`. Note that in order to create a *deep copy*, you need to define similar methods for `B` all the custom objects that `A` contains.

Comment: Ok so I think I'm really close here, but now though if a bKey appears twice in one B list, that gets processed twice so the output map entry has repeat values. Check the output [here](http://jdoodle.com/ia/xR0)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 groupingBy:**

You can use groupingBy feature as shown below:

*Here,*

1. I have used `flatMap()` to merge all the list of data into a single list.
2. I have used `groupingBy()` using id as a grouping element and then before collecting the data i have converted the data into `List<A>` using `Collectors.mapping()`

**B.java**

```
public class B {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public B(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**A.java**

```
public class A {
    private List<B> classBList;

    public A(List<B> classBList) {
        this.classBList = classBList;
    }

    public List<B> getClassBList() {
        return classBList;
    }

    public void setClassBList(List<B> classBList) {
        this.classBList = classBList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" +
                "classBList=" + classBList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<List<B>> listInput = List.of(
                List.of(new B(1, "Hello"), new B(1, "Hi"), new B(1, "Bye"), new B(1, "Yes")),
                List.of(new B(2, "No"), new B(2, "Go"), new B(2, "Yellow")),
                List.of(new B(2, "Joe"), new B(2, "Blow"))
        );

       Map<Integer,List<A>> output =
           listInput.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(B::getId,
                           Collectors.mapping(x -> 
                                   new A(List.of(new B(x.getId(), x.getName())))
                                   ,Collectors.toList())));

        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{1=[A{classBList=[B{id=1, name='Hello'}]}, A{classBList=[B{id=1, name='Hi'}]}, A{classBList=[B{id=1, name='Bye'}]}, A{classBList=[B{id=1, name='Yes'}]}],

2=[A{classBList=[B{id=2, name='No'}]}, A{classBList=[B{id=2, name='Go'}]}, A{classBList=[B{id=2, name='Yellow'}]}, A{classBList=[B{id=2, name='Joe'}]}, A{classBList=[B{id=2, name='Blow'}]}]}
```

Comment: I get a can't reference a non-static method from a static context error on the Collection::stream usage, which I think when working with lambdas means there's some kind of type mismatch.